# parse C header file to determine all defined macros

Tags: c, parsing, macros, header, include

I want to parse header file to fetch all constant macros like:

```
#define ARRSIZE 10
#define WORDSIZE 32
#define TOTALSIZE (ARRSIZE * WORDSIZE)
```

And create a list and an array such as:

```
# define XARRSIZE 0
# define XWORDSIZE 1
# define XTOTALSIZE 2

int table[] = {ARRSIZE, WORDSIZE, TOTALSIZE}
// Now, table[XWORDSIZE] will fetch value of WORDSIZE.
```

So, I want to ignore the following:

1. All comments.
2. Structure (C `struct`) declarations.
3. `extern` function declarations.
4. `typedef`s.

An approach can be write a parser using lex and yacc. But, this task seems much simpler. Is there a way to iterate over all constant macros in header file using tool such as 'cpp'?

Please suggest any better approach.

Comment: Macros always start with `#define MACRONAME`.  This doesn't sound like it's going to be very difficult to parse (so long as you don't care about things inside `#ifdef` and so on).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Don't forget about multi-line macros.

Comment: You could do it by implementing it in a [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) parser.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Sure, but from the OP's description, it sounds like all that's needed is to capture the `#define MACRONAME`.

Comment: Does `gcc -E -dM` works for you ?

Comment: All solutions which depend on extracting `#define` should also keep track of whether the term is used in a string. In fact, it may be in a string *and* be at the start of a line (`<NL>` is an actual newline here, it doesn't seem to be possible to post multi-line comments): `"foo \<NL>#define x 0 \<NL>bar"` is the string `foo #define x o bar`. Seems crazy to me, but trying a few MSVC compilers seems to confirm this.

Comment: Using "cpp <filename> -dD", I can filter out comments and collapse multiline #defines to single line. It also handles conditional macro expansion with #ifdef etc.

Comment: @alexandre-c, I tried `gcc -E -dM`. `gcc -E -dD` seems more useful because source markers can help me filter out #defines easily.

Comment: @mivi: Well, it seems to me that the easiest way should be to combine `gcc -E -dD` with some `awk` one liner, like in @Let_Me_Be's answer.

Comment: Thanks @alexandre-c. I think final solution will consist of first `gcc -E -dD` followed by `awk` and then `simple parsing of file` to fetch only the relevant #defines.

Comment: There's probably no need to parse anything nor re-invent the wheel. Some compilers support the option to dump all `#defined` macros in a text file. That way, you can have the compiler weed out compiler switches like `#ifdef` for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want a list of macros:

```
awk '/#define/{ print $2 }' <source.h
```

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirement "Ignore all comments".

Comment: There can be whitespace between the `#` and the `define`. I can't remember off the top of my head whether there can be whitespace between the start of the line and the `#`. Also I'm pretty sure multi-line macros are possible in C.

Comment: Doesn't ignore string literals that happen to contain things that look like preprocessor directives, either.  To do this right, you need a full lexer.